# Ayuda con tarea de programación C++ (taquilla de zoologico)

Tags: c++

Estas son las instrucciones de realización del programa:

1. Desarrolla el análisis, diseño e implementación de un programa que se utilice en la taquilla de un zoológico con las siguientes consideraciones:
2. Pregunta el tipo de cliente que puede ser: A) Adulto con costo de $120, B) Niño con costo de $60 y C) Adulto mayor con costo de $40.
3. Después de cada venta, el sistema preguntará si desea otro boleto con las opciones S/N, el programa se seguirá ejecutando hasta que la respuesta sea N.
4. Al finalizar, el programa dará el total de boletos vendidos de cada categoría y el total de dinero recaudado.

Este es el programa que realicé:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
char opcion;
char seguir;

const int N = 60;
const int A = 120;
const int AM = 40;
int total = 0;
int cantA = 0;
int cantN = 0;
int cantAM = 0;

do{

cout << "Escribe el boleto que desea comprar: "<< endl;
cout << "Boleto para ninos (N) = $60 \n" << "Boleto para adultos (A): $120 \n" << "Boleto para adultos mayores (AM)= $40 \n"<< endl;

cin >> opcion;
if (opcion == 'N' || opcion == 'n'){
    cantN++;
    total = total + N;
 }else if (opcion == 'a' || opcion == 'A') {
    cantA++;
    total= total + A;
 }else if (opcion == 'AM'|| opcion == 'am'){
    cantAM++;
    total = total + AM;
    }

cout << "¿Desea comprar otro boleto? \n"<< endl;
cout << "Escriba si (S) y o no (N) \n";
cin >> seguir;

}while (seguir == 's' || seguir == 'S');
cout << "Boletos vendidos por categoría: \n"<< endl;
cout << "Total vendido ninos: " << cantN<< endl;
cout << "Total vendido adultos: " << cantA<< endl;
cout << "Total vendido adultos mayores: " << cantAM<< endl;
cout << "CANTIDAD A PAGAR = $" << total;

}
```

El problema sucede cuando se ejecuta el programa, ya que si solo se compran boletos para niños y adultos funciona bien, pero al momento de querer comprar boletos para adultos mayores o se termina el programa o se agregan datos no ingresados.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Hace mucho que no veo C, así que puede que solo este divagando. Si no recuerdo mal, a la hora de comparar texto, no se debería utilizar comillas simples: == 'AM'. Simplemente para confirmar, prueba tu codigo, pero en vez de usar AM, usa solamente M.

Comment: Hola, acabo de realizar los cambios al programa y tienes razón. Olvidé que char solo puede almacenar un solo carácter, entonces al momento de escribir AM no lo leía y se iba directo a la siguiente instrucción. Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que usas la opción `"AM"` para adulto mayor, pero la variable `opcion` es un `char` (un solo byte). Puedes usar "M" o usar las opciones "A", "B" y "C" tal como lo sugieren las instrucciones.